# How to create a flag based on several conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2 columns (ID and Year). I want to create a 3rd column called "FLAG" that has output based on the following conditions **(all grouped by the ID)**:

- If data exists for 2020 or 2021 (but not both), then output "Gap"
- If data exists for 2020 and 2021, then output "Ap21"
- If data exists for 2020, 2021, and 2022, then output "Ap22"
- If data does not exist for both 2020 and 2021 (or for any other instance that's not the 3 conditions above), then output "notupdated"

I put an example of how I would like my dataframe to look in the end.

```
  data <- data.frame("ID" = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D"),  
  Year" = c(2019, 2021, 2022, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2018, 2019), "Flag" 
  = c("Gap", "Gap", "Gap", "Ap21", "Ap21", "Ap21", "Ap22", "Ap22", "Ap22", "Ap22", 
  "notupdated", "notupdated"))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would explore this option (in the `tidyverse`):  https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html    - there are base-R alternatives if you don't like tidyverse syntax/dependency.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover just some ifelse statements, but I think the order I'm doing it is incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

data |>
  mutate(
    Flag = case_when(
      all(c(2020, 2021, 2022) %in% Year) ~ "Ap22",
      all(c(2020, 2021) %in% Year) ~ "Ap21",
      any(c(2020, 2021) %in% Year) ~ "Gap",
      .default = "notupdated"
    ),
    .by = ID
  )
```

Output:

```
   ID Year       Flag
1   A 2019        Gap
2   A 2021        Gap
3   A 2022        Gap
4   B 2019       Ap21
5   B 2020       Ap21
6   B 2021       Ap21
7   C 2019       Ap22
8   C 2020       Ap22
9   C 2021       Ap22
10  C 2022       Ap22
11  D 2018 notupdated
12  D 2019 notupdated
```

Comment: I like the `.default`.

Comment: @Chris thats your "else" when doing a `case_when()`

Answer (score 1):

If the rules should work independently here's an alternative.
 Especially rule "*exists for 2020 or 2021 (but not both), then output "Gap"*" needs more than just `any(c(2020, 2021) %in% Year)`

Example

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(one = Year == 2020, two = Year == 2021, three = Year == 2022, 
         Flag = case_when(
                  (!any(one) | !any(two)) & (any(one) | any(two)) ~ "Gap"), 
         .by = ID) %>%
  select(-c(one, two, three))
   ID Year Flag
1   A 2019  Gap
2   A 2021  Gap
3   A 2022  Gap
4   B 2019 <NA>
5   B 2020 <NA>
6   B 2021 <NA>
7   C 2019 <NA>
8   C 2020 <NA>
9   C 2021 <NA>
10  C 2022 <NA>
11  D 2018 <NA>
12  D 2019 <NA>
```

Applied on all rules

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(one = Year == 2020, two = Year == 2021, three = Year == 2022, 
         Flag = case_when(
                  (!any(one) | !any(two)) & (any(one) | any(two)) ~ "Gap",
                  any(one) & any(two) & !any(three) ~ "Ap21", 
                  any(one) & any(two) & any(three) ~ "Ap22", 
                  !any(one) & !any(two) & !any(three) ~ "notupdated"), .by = ID) %>% 
  select(-c(one, two, three))
   ID Year       Flag
1   A 2019        Gap
2   A 2021        Gap
3   A 2022        Gap
4   B 2019       Ap21
5   B 2020       Ap21
6   B 2021       Ap21
7   C 2019       Ap22
8   C 2020       Ap22
9   C 2021       Ap22
10  C 2022       Ap22
11  D 2018 notupdated
12  D 2019 notupdated
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @jan 's answer is great, this is just reasoning about this problem
and much more convoluted.

```
library(cgwtools) # provides an rle for sequences, `seqle`, very handy...
length(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'A')])$lengths)
[1] 2 
# any gap is a gap
(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'B')])$values)+(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'B')])$lengths) -1
[1] 2021
(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'C')])$values)+(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'C')])$lengths) -1
[1] 2022
(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'D')])$values)+(cgwtools::seqle(data$Year[which(data$ID == 'D')])$lengths) -1
[1] 2019
# and use for Flag logic
```

Not `base`, but `seqle` can come in real handy.